# MacBook Pro will boot only after a SMC reset

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, ssd, power-management

I replaced the hard drive in my MacBook Pro (mid-2010) with a SSD one. I installed Mac OS X 10.9. At first the installer wasn't able to find the new SSD drive, because of a error: "SerialATAPI device reconfiguration did not complete successfully."

Following a friend's advice I reset the SMC, and the installer worked perfectly.

Now I have a working system, but every time I boot it I have to do a SMC reset, otherwise the system is not booting, and I see a blinking folder instead of the usual Apple.

That means that: "no bootable device has been found" http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2674

Is there anyway to have my system booting without a SMC reset before every boot?

I tried many times with a NVRAM reset, but it didn't help. Also this answer did not help: [MacBook Pro Mid 2009 does not boot without resetting system management control (SMC)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32007/macbook-pro-mid-2009-does-not-boot-without-resetting-system-management-control)

Comment: Good question. You might consider adding info on SSD and particular setup for other o take clues and maybe just share that information.